# MPEG-DASH streaming live using encoded stream buffer

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-4

I have been trying to implement HTTP live streaming using mpeg-dash but need guidance on some issues.

**Provided :**

- I have audio and video encoded stream in buffered input.
- a direct mpeg-2 transport stream for above is also available in a buffer.

**Current approach :**

1. Save the transport stream into chunks of fixed length.
2. use ffmpeg to extract video stream.
   `ffmpeg -i latest_chunk.ts -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 -b:v 600k -y -an output_video_stream.mp4`
3. use ffmpeg to extract video stream.
       `ffmpeg -i latest_chunk.ts -c:a aac -b:a 128k -y -vn output_audio_stream.mp4`
4. use mp4box to create dash segments and mpd.
       `mp4box -dash 7000 -profile live output_video_stream.mp4 output_audio_stream.mp4 -out manifest.mpd`
5. A server running continuously in another thread serves the generated mpd and segments.

**Issues :**

- The above approach gives a considerable amount of latency. Can this be done more efficiently?
- I want to know if there is a method to take directly encoded streams buffer as input and produce mpeg-dash segments and mpd. HTTP server will do the rest. If there is, please provide an example.
- Also i provided the length of the transport stream chunks (in sec) in mp4box as argument `-mpd-refresh 12`, but the player only requests for the mpd once, plays the segments, and stops. It also does not include minimumUpdatePeriod attribute in the generated mpd file
  `mp4box -dash 7000 -profile live -mpd-refresh 12 output_video_stream.mp4 output_audio_stream.mp4 -out manifest.mpd`
- Does the mpeg-dash has support for mpeg-2 encoded media streams?

Any advice/solution/reference for the same is appreciated.

Comment: Is it better to parse the mpeg stream and generate an mpd file ourselves or use tools like mp4box? I want to avoid using third party solutions like bitmovin.

Comment: Just write the stream to a named pipe and do the rest with ffmpeg or mp4box consuming from the named pipe. Also one question per post please.